# Berkeley DB Intel - ARM portability

Tags: database, linux, arm, intel, berkeley-db

Does Berkeley DB provide portablity between different archtecture types? I've read that db's are portable between 32 and 64 bit machines with different byte orders, but what's about different arch types? Because I tried to open db created on ARM machine on Intel and failed.

Comment: A wild guess - maybe this is caused by big-endian architecture vs. little-endian.

Comment: But they do claim byte order doesn't matter: " Databases can be moved between 32- and 64-bit machines, as well as between little- and big-endian machines" (from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/berkeleydb/db-faq-095848.html)

Answer (score 0):

BerkeleyDB provides portability between different endian environments for its own variables, but not for the data itself.

Note that a very common BerkeleyDB error is to use little endian keys for a B-Tree database,
Use big endian keys on B-Tree databases to preserve performance, swab the bytes on little endian platforms.